# A better way to make a Node app run forever on a Linux server?

Tags: node.js, upstart, forever, nohup, monit

currently I use `nohup` and `forever.js` to run my app on the server (Linux) without interruption:

`nohup forever app.js > logs &`

plus I have a cron script that checks if my `neo4j` database is online and relaunches it if necessary.

However, sometimes my app quits anyway and doesn't get relaunched.

I read [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/09/deploy-nodejs/) that a better way of keeping a `node.js` running `upstart` and `monit`.

Does anyone have experience doing that and is it really functioning better?

What would be the commands to use to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: you can look at pm2 https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: "*However, sometimes my app quits anyway...*" I would look into why the app quits. It should never happen and is the real issue here.

Comment: @davidkonrad totally agree with you — the reason is that it's hosted on WebFaction on a shared server and sometimes my Neo4J database consumes too much memory (I have a limit there), so they kill all the processes and that's why I think that nohup forever restart doesn't work (although theoretically it should). You're right I should look into memory-management but I'm still at the "make it work" stage :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used PM2 with Keymetrics in production env which is quite reliable and lean

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/monitoring/

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: Do you have to pay for the Keymetrics account? Or free is good to go? And could you provide a bit more details in your answer how you deploy PM2? Thank you so much!

Comment: Free is good to go at start for Keymetrics. I think the doc under pm2 github repo is clear enough. Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: this is such a life-saver. amazing stuff. i remember having to set it up with forever.js and launch it through nohup, but this is waaaaaay better! looks solid. thanks!